# How to install signing certificates so that they are listed in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4, code-signing

I need to code sign my Mac App. I obtained the certificates from the Apple's developer portal and would like to install it. The certificates are listed in `Keychain Access`. How to I go about doing this so that it is listed in Xcode 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reinstalled OSX without backing up my certificates. Therefore, when I re-downloaded it from Apple it will not work. I had to recreate the certificates from the `Developer Certificate Utility` for it to work again.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue.  In my case, it was caused by my installing the certificates in the incorrect ("System") keychain.  They should be in the "login" keychain.  The Keychain Access tool will let you drag and drop them into the login group.

This is what it should look like:

[image: correct location]

Once I did this, the signing option appeared in XCode:

[image]

Comment: +1 for being new to SO and already using images in answers. This is rare!